# prevent specific sub (this) tag for event in jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu

I have this code for my menus:

```
$('div.content ul.menu li.expanded')
.mouseenter(function() {
    $('ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li').slideUp(300);
    $(this).find('li.leaf').slideDown(300);
});
```

**Third** line hides all sub-menus first and then **forth** line shows preferred sub menus again.
I've got problems using this code in different situations which is hard to explain.

**All I need is, in third line**: hide all sub-menus except the ones under ('this') which I have in my function.

Anyone knows a way to achieve this?

Comment: `$('ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li').not(this).slideUp(300);`?

Comment: @jensgram didn't work I need sth like: $('ul.menu li.expanded ul.menu li').not(this).find('li.leaf').slideUp(300);

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure when we can't see the HTML in question, but this might work:

```
$('div.content ul.menu li.expanded').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).find('li.leaf').slideDown(300).siblings().slideUp(300); 
});
```

Comment: menu structure is like: ul li ul li. nothing special

Comment: Without seeing the exact structure of your HTML, I can't provide any more suggestions.